Перечисление с тремя союзами «и». Нужны ли запятые?
Книги понравятся и более взрослым детям и их папам и мамам.
Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

Книги понравятся и более взрослым детям, и их папам и мамам.   Союз И...И. // Но лучше так: Книги понравятся и более взрослым детям, а также  их папам и мамам. Тогда И  — частица.

Скопление одинаковых согласных ( в данном случае  И ИХ) считается стилистическим недочетом (фонетическое неблагозвучие).  Избыток союзов И также не приветствуется. Желательно редактировать предложение.  https://www.yaneuch.ru/cat_12/shpargalka-po-stilistika-russkogo-yazyka/239195.2160725.page8.html

❶ Правильно с одной запятой:
Книги понравятся и (1) более взрослым детям, и (2) их папам и (3) мамам.

1. Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимися союзами и…и <...> ставится запятая...
2. При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом и, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов)...
Такие смысловые единства образуются словами с ассоциативными (часто антонимическими) связями: <...>
и отцу и матери

Первый пункт правил Розенталя относится к союзам 1, 2 (ставим запятую).
Второй пункт — к союзам 2, 3 (не ставим запятую).
❷ Примеры
В библиотеку действительно хочется приходить и детям, и их мамам и папам, бабушкам и дедушкам (из статьи).
Репетиционный экзамен даёт возможность и самим школьникам, и их папам и мамам ознакомиться не только с примерами самих заданий, но и с целым рядом организационных нюансов единого государственного экзамена... ("Североморские Вести").
Мы живем в обществе с утраченной традицией воспитания, где нужно помогать и детям, и их папам и мамам... ("Postimees").
Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами
